Run keycloak in docker container and behind a nginx reverse proxy, the admin console show error message for each realm
Run keycloak v26 in docker container and behind a nginx reverse proxy.
The database is  restored from a backup which dump from a keycloak v19.0.2, when the docker container start up first time, the database automaticlly upgraded.
When login the admin console, i can pass the password validation, and get into the console page, but got error message "Unable to determine error message." for each realm. Then i trace the http requests in browser, found that only one request failed by "502 bad gateway", that is:
/auth/admin/master/console/whoami

I locate related logs in nginx and keycloak:
nginx error logs:
2024/10/31 15:14:36 [error] 18794#18794: *79409565 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.13.91, server: sso.mydomain.com, request: "GET /auth/admin/master/console/whoami?currentRealm=master HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.10.0.89:8080/auth/admin/master/console/whoami?currentRealm=master", host: "sso.mydomain.com:8443"

keycloak logs:
2024-10-31 14:26:46,495 WARN  [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:401)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:434)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:255)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Here is my configurations:
nginx vhost configuration:
upstream sso-mydomain-com {
        server 10.10.0.89:8080;
}

server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  sso.mydomain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://sso-mydomain-com/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sso.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sso.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
}

server {
        listen       8443 ssl;
        server_name  sso.mydomain.com;
        error_log    /usr/local/nginx/logs/sso_err.log debug;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://sso-mydomain-com/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sso.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sso.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
}

keycloak docker compose.yml:
services:
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:26.0
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /opt/keycloak/themes:/opt/keycloak/themes
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    privileged: true
    command: start

keycloak environment variables:
KC_HOSTNAME=sso.mydomain.com
KC_DB=mysql
KC_DB_PASSWORD=********
KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://10.10.0.89:3306/keycloak
KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true

KC_PROXY_HEADERS=xforwarded
KC_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG

Any advice? Thanks a lot!
========== update ==========
I have do some more research:

map certificate files into keycloak container, and change domain name direct to keycloak container's ip address, it can work well.
map certificate files into keycloak container, and use nginx(running in other server) stream proxy, it works too. the nginx configuration part as below:

stream {
    upstream sso-keycloak {
        server 10.10.0.89:8443;
    }
    server {
        listen 8443;
        proxy_pass sso-keycloak;
    }
}


Have you tried setting buffer size by any chance? The error message you shared seems to be sometimes related to buffer size. recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream ref

yes, i did config nginx proxy buffer in http block as below:
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
but it seems didn't work, all error messages are same as before.

i see. i thought the problem was the buffer size. any luck with re-building nginx container after changing your nginx configurations?

Hi Kikito, thanks for your reply.
In my case, the nginx is running as a standalone server but not in container, after changing the proxy_buffer configuration, i just reload it by "nginx -s reload".
